# How to update rows and then delete all but one. Data deduplication

Tags: python, sql, r

Given a table like this:

| ID | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 01 | 5 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 01 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 00 | 4 | 8 | 1 | 1 |
| 00 | 4 | 8 | 1 | 1 |
| 00 | 4 | 8 | 1 | 1 |
| 03 | 6 | 4 | 0 | 0 |
| 03 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 03 | 6 | 4 | 0 | 0 |

How could I use SQL (T-SQL/SQL Server Mgt Studio), R, or Python to do the following in this order:

For each unique ID, update col A with the maximum value of A from all rows and then delete all rows except the one with the highest value in col B. I need to end up with only one row for a given ID.

Written another way; I have duplicate data and need to delete duplicate rows but only after ensuring I have the maximum value of col A from any duplicates applied to the row with the maximum value of col B. I want to only keep one row for a given ID but the row I want to keep is the one with the max col B. If there are multiple identical ID & col B rows, delete all but one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In R:

```
library(dplyr)
your_data %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(A = max(A)) %>%
  slice(which.max(B)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Or with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(your_data)
your_data[, A := max(A), by = ID][, .SD[which.max(B)], by = ID]
```

Answer (score 3):

In `SQL` using  `CTE`

```
with cte as (
  select id, max(a) a from your_table_name group by id
),
cteb as (
  select row_number() over (partition by id order by b desc) sn , 
  id, b, c, d from your_table_name
)

select id, a, b, c, d 
from cte  a inner join cteb b using(id) 
where sn = 1 
order by cast(id as integer)
```

Answer (score 2):

In Python:

```
(df.assign(A=df.groupby('ID')['A'].transform(max))
   .sort_values(by=['B'], ascending=False)
   .drop_duplicates(subset=['ID'])
)
```